# fixed packages introduce conflicting requirements for BinDeps:

Tags: julia, juno-ide

After installing JuliaPro_v0.6.0.1_build-78.exe from scratch I tried to update packages via Pkg.update() I've got the following Error message:

```
fixed packages introduce conflicting requirements for BinDeps: 
       available versions are 0.0.1, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.3, 0.2.4, 
0.2.5, 0.2.6, 0.2.7, 0.2.8, 0.2.9, 0.2.10, 0.2.11, 0.2.12, 0.2.13, 0.2.14, 
0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.3.3, 0.3.4, 0.3.5, 0.3.6, 0.3.7, 0.3.8, 0.3.9, 0.3.10, 0.3.11, 0.3.12, 0.3.13, 0.3.14, 0.3.15, 0.3.16, 0.3.17, 0.3.18, 0.3.19, 0.3.20, 0.3.21, 0.3.22, 0.3.23, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.4.4, 0.4.5, 0.4.7, 0.5.0 and 0.6.0
in update at base\pkg\pkg.jl:228
in #cd#1 at base\pkg\dir.jl:32
in withenv at base\env.jl:157
in cd at base\file.jl:59
in #3 at base\pkg\dir.jl:33
in update at base\pkg\entry.jl:461
in resolve at base\pkg\entry.jl:496
in check_requirements at base\pkg\query.jl:222
```

Trying to add an another Pkg leads to a same error message. Thus it is not possible to add further packages without solving this problem.

Any advice to resolve this problem are appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This just fixed it for me:

`Pkg.rm("BinDeps")`

The effect was downgrading `BinDeps` from `0.7.0` to `0.6.0`.

---

Out of curiosity I did `Pkg.update()` afterwards, which has brought `BinDeps` back to `0.7.0`, but it seems that previous conflicts are now gone.

I think the issue might have been that version `0.7.0` was installed but not registered as available.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Bindeps metadata was changed after the JuliaPro release due to some bugs in Bindeps. Downgrading Bindeps is the right solution.